# How to draw plus(+) using <line> tag in SVG?

Tags: user-interface, svg

**Below using points**

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200"
     style="stroke:`enter code here`rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />      
     </svg>
```

Comment: a + sign would require 2 lines.

Comment: But i am getting confused choosing the cordinates ,since it doesn't accepts negative points @RobertLongson.

Comment: sure it does, they are just off-screen. Why are you drawing a diagonal line if you want a + sign?

Comment: I am newbie,i tried using path tag also @RobertLongson

Comment: draw a + sign on graph paper. See what the co-ordinates are.

Comment: (-50,0) to (50,0) Horizontal Line and (0,50) to (0,-50) vertical line. @RobertLongson

Comment: Well that's round the origin but your space is 0,0 to 500, 210. You could use a viewBox to change that.

Comment: <svg height="400" width="400">  
  <path d="M 170 200 l 150 0" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <path d="M 250 175 l 0 100" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />  
</svg>   *used this one but i am not getting exact plus @RobertLongson

Comment: that's one line, a plus sign would require 2.

Comment: I used  'M0,-1 V1 M-1,0 H1' as path.Now its working thanks @RobertLongson :)

Comment: Useful pen that can help you visualise the process at https://codepen.io/anthonydugois/full/mewdyZ

Comment: yeah sure @Ruskin

Comment: @akshay-awate Okay, okay I get that there is a little learning curve on that and it has its limitation (e.g. only absolute not relative paths) ... but give it a chance. Try clicking "Reset Path" then build the path, looking at the generated path data in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your plus:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <line x1='0' y1='60' x2='120' y2='60' stroke='black' />
  <line x1='60' y1='0' x2='60' y2='120' stroke='black' />
</svg>
```

Just remove the second line to get a minus.

As pointed out in the comments, you just draw 2 lines. Each line has its 2 points. You seem to get confused with coordinates. By default, an SVG has the origin at the top left corner, so it does not require any negative coordinate.

If you want your origin at the center of the plus and use negative coordinates, you can, you need to change the `viewBox` property at the root in my example and replace the 2 zeros by 2 `-60`. It shifts the top left corner by half the width and height, essentially putting the coordinates `0,0` in the middle.